# matching two JSON ios with different valuekey on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsstring

I'm trying to implement get my JSON to be matched with another JSON that shared the same nodeID. I got no problem getting my 1 st set of JSON on my TableView. 
Here is the 1st set of my JSON

```
{
node_title: "Fumi",
nid: "9",
Body: "<p>Fumi Restaurant</p> ",
Shop Branch Reference: "<a href="/drupal/node/8">CTW</a>",
Shop Enterprise Reference: "<a href="/drupal/node/7">Fumi</a>",
Shop Service Time: [
"<div class="time-default"> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday 10:00am - 8:00pm</div> "
],
Shop User Reference: "<a href="/drupal/user/12">suppae</a>"
},
```

I got no problem getting this json of my tableview but the key is that I have to match Shop Branch Reference that has the nodeID inside with my 2nd Set of JSON that has the NID.

Here is my 2nd set of JSON

```
[
{
node_title: "CTW",
nid: "8"
},
{
node_title: "Siam Paragon",
nid: "2"
}
]
```

Basically I have to match Shop Branch Reference from the 1st with nid from the 2nd set. The problem is how can I get only the number after "node/ " to be matched with nid from the 2nd set.

Comment: you need to transform `Shop Branch Reference`'s value by substitution with regular expression. example: `/["][\/]drupal[\/]node[\/](?<number>\d)["]/`. it can be done more beautiful, but it is a good point to start ;)

Comment: Wow that's the whole new thing for me to learn. Thank you Gaussblurinc for guiding me the direction :) ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure, that I can help you, but ok, I will try.

For example, let's start with this site: 
[Ruby regular expression checker](http://rubular.com/r/UtiyQhHw9C)

Is it what you want? yes ;) but this is an alternative for you, ruby language.
You need [NSRegularExpression](http://rubular.com/r/UtiyQhHw9C) class.

What you need is sample of code:

```
NSString * pattern = @"[\"][\\/]drupal[\\/]node[\\/](\\d)[\"]";
NSString * searchIn = @"\"/drupal/node/8\"";
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSArray * matches =
[regex matchesInString:searchIn options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchIn length])];


for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSRange captureFirstGroup = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; // first group is `(\\d)` - whatever in (...)
    NSLog(@"I find!, %u x %u",captureFirstGroup.location,captureFirstGroup.length);
    NSLog(@"I find!, substring! %@",[searchIn substringWithRange:captureFirstGroup]);
}
```

Some tricks:

Capture groups are things between `(` and `)`. You can access to them like I do in example.

Good luck ;)